# Как подключиться по ssh под локальной учётной записью без пароля?

Tags: ssh, password, openssh

Я установил ssh сервер (sshd) на компьютер (Windows 10). Затем я попробовал подключиться к своей учётной записи (у которой нет пароля) по команде: `ssh COMP@localhost` на этом же компьютере, чтобы убедиться, что всё работает. В консоли появилось сообщение с запросом пароля, которого я не знаю `COMP@localhost's password:`.

Пробовал менять параметры в конфиге `sshd_config`

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
...
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

После перезагрузки при попытке подключиться стало появляться сообщение `COMP@localhost: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).`

Comment: в винде по-умолчанию все порты закрыты. откройте порт 22.

Comment: @AlexGlebe показанные сообщения намекают на очевидно открытый порт

Comment: PubkeyAuthentication=no и PasswordAuthentication=no выключает все способы. Включите одно из них *(PubkeyAuthentication yes)*.